# Exponential decay of the temperature of coffee

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

8. The table describes the cooling of a cup of coffee as it sits on your teacher’s desk in the math office. 
   Time (min) 0 4 8 12 16 20 
   Temperature (celsius)
   55 47 40 34 29 25

a) Calculate a, the cooling factor (rate at which the coffee cools per minute) of the coffee. Round 
your answer to two decimal places. 
b) Determine an equation for y, the temperature of the coffee in degrees Celsius after t minutes. 
c) Is your model a good predictor of the temperature of the coffee at any point in time? Explain.

Comment: if I were to use the table and search for the differences, I can find that it has a 2nd difference of -1 degrees celsius.  But this is what I believe is for every 4 minutes and here they want to know how much it decreased per minute.  I think I can use the formula y=C(a)^x where c is the initial amount, a is the amount it is decreasing by and x represents the number of minutes.  But I am not 100% sure about going about this for solving for how much it decreased per minute

Comment: so to get my amount it decreases per minute, would I simply divide -1 by 4?

Comment: this would give me -0.25 degrees celsius per minute if this is correct.

Comment: ... y=55(-0.25)^t?  Is this the right equation?  I just want to know if I have the decay rate in the proper form in the brackets.